# using a drop down menu to pull select query results into a form

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using a form to input new projects into my database.  One of the fields is Lead Writer.  I want to add a drop down menu to that field that will display the names of the lead writers from my database that the user can then select to populate that field.  I've managed to get the drop down to appear in the field, but my code isn't generating any names.  I tried setting up a function that would call those results, but it's obviously not working.  The form worked well prior to my changes, so it's not an issue connecting to the database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function query(){
$myNames = "SElECT LastName FROM Projects";
$result = $mysqli->query($myNames);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($myNames)){
echo '<option value=' . $record['LastName'] . '>' . $record['LastName'] . '</option>';
}
}

?>

<?php
    $connection->close();
?>
<form action="http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/NewProject.php" method="post">

<div class="fieldset">
        <fieldset>

        Project: <input type="text" name="Project value="<?php if(isset($Project)){ echo $Project; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ProjectErr)){ echo $ProjectErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        Client: <input type="text" name="Client" value="<?php if(isset($Client)){ echo $Client; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($ClientErr)){ echo $ClientErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        Lead Writer: <select name="dropdown">
                     <?php query() ?>
                     </select>
               <br><br>
        Date Received: <input type="text" name="DateReceived" value="<?php if(isset($DateReceived)){ echo $DateReceived; } ?>">
        <span class="error">* <?php if(isset($DateReceivedErr)){ echo $DateReceivedErr; } ?></span>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
     </fieldset>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Edited Code:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<?php

function test_input($data){
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "oldga740_SeniorProject";

// create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


function query($mysqli){
    $myNames = "SELECT LastName FROM Projects";
    if(!$result = $mysqli->query($myNames)) {die($mysqli->error);} // check for error message
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ // if there is rows
        while($record = $result->fetch_array()){
            echo '<option value="' . $record['LastName'] . '">' . $record['LastName'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else { // if there is no rows
      echo '<option value="">No Rows</option>';
    }
}
?>

<form>

Lead Writer: <select name="dropdown">
                            <?php query($mysqli); ?>
                     </select>  

</form>

<?php
$connection->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd Edit:

```
// create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


function query($connection){
    $myNames = "SELECT LastName FROM Projects";
    if(!$result = $connection->query($myNames)) {die($mysqliconnection->error);} // check for error message
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ // if there is rows
        while($record = $result->fetch_array()){
            echo '<option value="' . $record['LastName'] . '">' . $record['LastName'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else { // if there is no rows
      echo '<option value="">No Rows</option>';
    }
}?>

<?php
    $connection->close();
?>

<form>

Lead Writer: <select name="dropdown">
                            <?php query($connection); ?>
                     </select>  

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable scope issue - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. `$mysqli` is undefined in your `function query()`. You need to pass it as a param. Also, you were trying to do `mysqli_fetch_array()` on the query string, instead of the mysqli result. I have updated it to the OO `->fetch_array()`.

```
function query($mysqli){
    $myNames = "SELECT LastName FROM Projects";
    $result = $mysqli->query($myNames);
    while($record = $result->fetch_array()){
        echo '<option value=' . $record['LastName'] . '>' . $record['LastName'] . '</option>';
    }
}
```

You will also need to pass it in your call

```
Lead Writer: <select name="dropdown">
                 <?php query($mysqli); ?>
             </select>
```

---

You can add some debugging to find out why it is not printing

```
function query($mysqli){
    $myNames = "SELECT LastName FROM Projects";
    if(!$result = $mysqli->query($myNames)) {die($mysqli->error);} // check for error message
    if($result->num_rows > 0){ // if there is rows
        while($record = $result->fetch_array()){
            echo '<option value="' . $record['LastName'] . '">' . $record['LastName'] . '</option>';
        }
    } else { // if there is no rows
      echo '<option value="">No Rows</option>';
    }
}
```

---

per your edit - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34257335/revisions

Your mysqli connection is `$connection`

```
// create connection
$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

so not sure why you are trying to use `$mysqli`

```
$mysqli->query($myNames)
```

as `$connection` != `$mysqli`.

As you are doing the query in a function, you don't need to rename all instances of `$mysqli` to `$connection`, as you can just change to

```
Lead Writer: <select name="dropdown">
    <?php query($connection); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I didn't think I had it set up to fetch the right result, but It's still not returning any results though.

Comment: Just noticed that you have `while($result =...` but trying to access `$record['LastName']`. Will update my answer

Comment: It's still not returning results.  I've set up other pages using loops, but I've displayed them in tables.  This is my first attempt at having the select results to display in a drop down menu.

Comment: I have updated the answer with some ways to debug why you are not getting the select to populate. (1) check for error messages, (2) check if any rows are returned.

Comment: I stripped everything else out of the file and left the bare code to see if if maybe there was something else on the page that was causing the query to not return any results.  I don't get error messages of any kind.  I'm going to update my post to show you.

Comment: To your updated code - So your mysqli connection is `$connection`-> `$connection = new mysqli(...)` so why are you trying to use `$mysqli` -> `$mysqli->query($myNames)`? Try changing `<?php query($mysqli); ?>` to `<?php query($connection); ?>`

Comment: I've used the same connection throughout my web page.  I initially wasn't usng $mysqli when setting my function. I tried that, but it didn't work either.

Comment: So update all the `$mysqli` with `$connection`. Then update here with the updated code if it still does not exist.

Comment: first glance, this is wrong - `die($mysqliconnection->error);`. Needs to be `die($connection->error;)`. clearly not the issue, but would help get any error message.